Why is my Nextjs Route Interception Modal not working?
I am trying to loosely follow this guide to implement route interception into my Nextjs test app. I am using Nextjs app router. I have already successfully implemented parallel routing. My end goal is to implement a route interception modal similar to the above guide.
Here is my deployed test app before trying to implement route interception. The rough segment structure for this example is as follows:

app/

@modal/

create/

page.tsx


[...catchAll]/

page.tsx


default.tsx


api/

notes/


create/

page.tsx


lib/
ui/
page.tsx
layout.tsx



Here is my deployed test app after trying to implement route interception. The rough segment structure for this example is as follows:

app/

@modal/

(.)create/

page.tsx


[...catchAll]/

page.tsx


default.tsx


api/

notes/


create/

page.tsx


lib/
ui/
page.tsx
layout.tsx



The only change between these two commits/deployments was changing /app/@modal/create to /app/@modal/(.)create. After hours of debugging I think I've narrowed my problem down to this.
/app/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import './globals.css';
import { Providers } from './providers';
import { lusitana } from './ui/fonts';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { ThemeSwitcher } from './ui/theme-switch';


export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout(props: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  modal: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="max-h-full h-full">
      <body className={`${lusitana.className} antialiased max-h-full h-full`}>
        <Providers>
          <div className="max-h-full h-full">
            <Toaster
              toastOptions={{
                duration: 4000,
                position: 'top-right',
              }}
            />
            <ThemeSwitcher className="absolute t-0 l-0 m-3" />
            <div className="text-center">{props.children}</div>
            <div className="text-center">{props.modal}</div>
          </div>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

/app/create/page.tsx
export default function Page() {
  return 'create main';
}

/app/@modal/create/page.tsx or /app/@modal/(.)create/page.tsx
export default function Page() {
  return (
    'create modal'
  );
}

Extra info can be added as requested.

What is in your default.tsx? It should contain
export default function Default() {
    return null;
}

